# HttpHandler to handle all kinds of URL's in Mono Apache/XSP in order to build a REST service

Tags: asp.net, apache, mono, mod-mono, xsp

I want to develop my own REST service, so I've created an `IHttpHandler` that is configured with `verb="*"` and `path="*"`, the the application in `~/MyRESTsrv/` will handle any derived URL.

This approach works good in IIS7 with "integrated mode" and apparently in IIS6 if you map all the extensions to "aspnet_isapi.dll".

Is this possible in Apache/XSP with Mono? Do I have to do something special or it will work out of the box?

Cheers.

PS: Is XSP a small web server that works with Apache in order to serve asp.net pages or it's just an web server you can use for development and has nothing to do with Apache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll work out of the box with XSP and with Apache you'll need "SetHandler mono".

XSP is just like cassini, so nothing to do with Apache. It's lightweight and only really for development or testing.